# Как посчитать время, за которое отсортировался список?

Tags: python, время

```
import timeit

import numpy as np

def bubble_sort(nums):
    # Устанавливаем swapped в True, чтобы цикл запустился хотя бы один раз
    swapped = True
    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
            if nums[i] > nums[i + 1]:
                # Меняем элементы
                nums[i], nums[i + 1] = nums[i + 1], nums[i]
                # Устанавливаем swapped в True для следующей итерации
                swapped = True


a = list(np.random.permutation(100))
bubble_sort(a)
print(a)
```

Не понимаю как, надо воспользоваться модулем *timeit*, как?

Comment: А что там понимать-то? Бери любой пример и подставь туда свой код.

Comment: В Jupyter Notebook (и в Google Colab) вообще просто, там магический метод есть, пишете просто `%timeit func()` и всё.

Comment: Но нужно учитывать, что в вашем случае `bubble_sort` меняет массив, к которому обращается, а это влияет на скорость сортировки при последующих обращениях, поэтому лучше вынести в отдельную функцию генерацию данных и применение bubble_sort, и вот уже эту функцию тестировать через `timeit`. Иначе замеры будут не совсем адекватные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я всегда за то, что-бы искать наипростейшие и самые понятные решения задачи.
Поэтому в вашем случае можно, конечно, искать и более красивые решения, в можно и вот так, в лоб:

```
a = list(np.random.permutation(100))
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
bubble_sort(a)
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
```

Результат:

```
0.0008262999999999465
```

Если очень хочется, то можно немного поизвращаться:

```
t1 = timeit.Timer("bubble_sort(list(np.random.permutation(100)))", "from __main__ import bubble_sort; import numpy as np")
print("Время выполнения:",t1.timeit(number=1), "миллисекунд")
```

Результат:

```
Время выполнения: 0.0009164999996755796 миллисекунд
```

А можно вообще обойтись библиотекой time (а timeit применять там, где ей место  -  при работе в консоли)

```
import time
start_time = time.clock()
bubble_sort(a)
stop_time=time.clock()
print(stop_time - start_time)
```

Результат:

```
0.0008161999999174441
```

Comment: [`timeit.default_timer` это более подходящая функция для измерения производительности по сравнение с `time.clock`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25823885/4279) (на старых версиях, на Windows `default_timer` указывал на `time.clock`), консоль тут ни причём.